# How to send a keystroke to another computer

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I was trying to figure out how I can send a keystroke to another computer. All I see help for is how to send it to another application.

can you output to the keyboard usb port?

Comment: You need programs running on both machines that can communicate with each other by some means. You'll need the owner of the other machine to agree to this.

Comment: The software will be ran by my machine. I have a harness from my machine to other machine. The software on my machine checkes other machine's inputs/outputs threw harness. But after every step on other machine , you have to press F3.  Can i simulate that from my machine? I own both machines.

Comment: You just need programs running on both machines and a communication channel between them. That's all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I saw this , which was wondering if you ever tried anything like this.  but this way i only need the program on 1 machine not both. https://www.l3sys.com/files/keyat5.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to send keystrokes directly to another computer but..

You can write a software which establishes a connection between this two computers.

**I would prefer a communication over TCP/IP (delphi has some ready to use components for that)**

**Alternatively** you could use communication over **file transfer**. For programmer beginners this is not a very difficult task.
Create on each computer a **network share** called "inbox"
Now you can write from each application to the share of your destination computer your message files.
On the destination computer your software would read those files (containing your keystrokes)

These are just two possible solutions for your very vague described problems.